# Detect IE Third-party Cookie and Mixed Content Setting

Tags: internet-explorer, settings

Is it possible to programmatically detect if IE Mixed Content is enabled and/or Third-party Cookie is set to Accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from locally running code. Look at the ProcessURLAction method on the IInternetSecurity manager (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537136(v=vs.85).aspx).

(You could look at the registry, but this isn't supported and you'd have to understand the precedence of keys and MapURLToZone anyway)